# Transfering algorithms AsymptoticOutputTracking to Matlab-Simulink

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica, simulink

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/241776/transfering-algorithms-asymptoticoutputtracking-to-matlab-simulink

The following system is built and modeled in simulink.

[image]

I am interested in the transient process in the variable $x$.

[image]

This system is described by the following differential equations:

\begin{cases} \frac{dx}{dt}=-H(t) \ \frac{dH}{dt}+h H(t)=\frac{df}{dt} \end{cases}

where $f=e^{-(x(t)-x_e)^2}$,$x_e$=0,$h$=1

If we numerically solve this system in `Mathematica`, then we get:

```
Clear["Derivative"]

ClearAll["Global`*"]

pars = {xs = -1, xe = 0, h = 1}

f = Exp[-(x[t] - xe)^2]

sys = NDSolve[{x'[t] == -H[t], H'[t] + h H[t] == D[f, t], x[0] == xs, 
   H[0] == Exp[-(xs - xe)^2]}, {x, H}, {t, 0, 10}]

Plot[{Evaluate[x[t] /. sys]}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> Full, 
 PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

We can see that the results from `Simulink` and `Mathematica` are the same.

Next, I want to do the following. Using the `AsymptoticOutputTracker` command, control the variable $x$ according to the specified reference law, i.e. the system of equations will take the form:

\begin{cases} \frac{dx}{dt}=-H(t)+u(t) \ \frac{dH}{dt}+h H(t)=\frac{df}{dt} \end{cases}

As a reference signal I use $r_1=e^{-t}+1$ with decay rate $p_1=-5$. As a controlled output, I use the variable $x$, and with $f$ I just see what happens in the end. There is my code:

(***)

```
Clear["Derivative"]

ClearAll["Global`*"]

f = Exp[-(x[t] - xe)^2]

asys = AffineStateSpaceModel[{x'[t] == -H[t] + u[t], 
    H'[t] + h H[t] == D[f, t]}, {{x[t], xs}, {H[t], 
     Exp[-(xs - xe)^2]}}, {u[t]}, {x[t], f}, t] // Simplify

pars1 = {Subscript[r, 1] -> Exp[-t] + 1, Subscript[p, 1] -> -5}

fb = AsymptoticOutputTracker[
   asys, {Subscript[r, 1]}, {Subscript[p, 1]}] // Simplify

pars = {xs = -1, xe = 0, h = 1}

csys = SystemsModelStateFeedbackConnect[asys, fb] /. pars1 // 
   Simplify // Chop

plots = {OutputResponse[{csys}, {0, 0}, {t, 0, 10}]}

Plot[{plots[[1, 1]], Exp[-t] + 1}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotPoints -> 200]

Plot[{plots[[1, 2]]}, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 200]
```

[image]

[image]

In general, everything works, but now **QUESTION**:

And how to transfer the feedback signal generated by the `AsymptoticOutputTracker` command to simulink and in general simulate all this in simulink?

`I would be grateful for the help and advice of respected experts`.

Comment: It's better to add the output of 2nd code sample to the question, too.

Comment: @xzczd please, help me

Comment: I'm sorry, but I know nothing about simulink.

Comment: @xzczd Do you know what structural scheme is used to construct the asymptotic output tracking? Maybe, something like that: [https://ibb.co/QHsRjGY](https://ibb.co/QHsRjGY)

Comment: Not sure if I've understood your question, but it's mentioned in **Details and Options** section of document of `AsymptoticOutputTracker` that: "`AsymptoticOutputTracker` is based on `FeedbackLinearize`, and any residual dynamics must be stable for valid results. "

Comment: @xzczd. Well, maybe this help. Thanks !